# Are there volcanic forest elves in Golarion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion, elf

I am creating an elf character and want to take the alternate racial feature that gives Fire Resistance 5. It says it is a product of the environment where the elf lived.

Are there any forests on volcanic mountains in the Golarian setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are forests near both *inactive* and *active* volcanos, but not fire or magma elves in Golarion. I checked [Elves of Golarion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy85el?Pathfinder-Companion-Elves-of-Golarion) and the [Inner Sea Races](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9g9v?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Races), both have no mention of this.

That variant is on the [Advanced Race Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8rv2?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Race-Guide), which is a setting neutral book (for most of it, at least). However, there are many elves who live in the deserts of Garundi and this racial trait would fit them perfectly.

Checking [Giantslayer #5: Anvils of Fire](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9et7?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-95-Anvil-of-Fire), there is an article called **Volcanos of Golarion**, which lists many possible citizens of volcanos: Fire yai, fire giants, dragons (red, magma and underworld), obsidian gargoyles, elementals (fire and magma), magmins, mephits (fire and magma), salamanders, thoqquas, efreeti, magma oozes, flame beheaded, burning skeletons, red wyrm raveners, and finally, ghosts and wraith of victims. No elves, maybe dead elves.

Considering that the article also lists the most known volcanos, I will comment on those:

- **Droskar's Crag**, named after the dwarven god of toil and suffering, got its name after it exploded in the face of many dwarves who lived in there in their underground cities. Its located in the [Darkmoon Vale](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Darkmoon_Vale), [Andoran](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Andoran).
- **Eye of Unmaker**, here lies the orc fortress, [Brimstone Haruspex](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Brimstone_Haruspex), where orc oracles get visions of apocalyptic futures by inhaling the volcano smokes, and orc chieftains bring living sacrifices to trade for prophecies. Located in the [Hold of Belkzen](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Hold_of_Belkzen).
- **Mhar Massif**, this is a large volcano, surrounded by dozens of smaller ones, and is named after a Great Old One called [Mhar](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Mhar), which is said to live inside the volcano. Its the home of a runelord and his giant slaves, and is located in [Varisia](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Varisia).
- **Mount Keeba**, nicknamed "the Smoker" by those who live in the [Shackles](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Shackles), its always semi-active and home of three seers called the [Keeba's Eyes](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Keeba%27s_Eyes). There is a small village nearby called [Plumetown](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Plumetown).
- **Terwa Lake**, surrounded by ancient ruined cities, this volcano in the Mwangi is only inhabited by [rusalkas](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Rusalka), and has a crystal water lake on its caldera, but with deadly gases gathering underneath. A powerful necromancer lives there.
- **Zom Kullan**, is actually the capital city of the nagas, in the heart of a massive volcano. They keep themselves safe through powerful rituals that also empower their matriarch. Its located in [Nagajor](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Nagajor), [Tian Xia](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Tian_Xia).
- **Asuulek's Mouth**, another semi-active volcano that sends ash and smoke into surrounding areas. Its located in [Osirion](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Osirion).

Answer (score 0):

[Darkmoon Wood](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Darkmoon_Wood) may fit your needs, located in Northern Andoran (inner sea region).

> ## Geography
>
> Darkmoon Wood is located in Darkmoon Vale, at the base of Droskar's
>   Crag, along the banks of the River Foam in northern Andoran, near the border of Isger and Druma.

and [Droskar's Crag](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Droskar%27s_Crag) is an active volcano. Not expert enough on Golarion to know whether this would make a bad home for an elf, but [Falcon's Hollow](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Falcon%27s_Hollow) (the closest settlement, being roughly 8 miles south) has 14 elves in it's demographics (out of about 1400), so there's at least a small handful in the area.

Comment: "Never a stronghold for elves, even at the height
of their power, Arthfell Forest (and later, Darkmoon
Wood) was always seen as the sovereign home of
Queen Syntira of the fey. As a result, at most, the elves
maintained a small enclave surrounding its embassy.
When the elves retreated from the world, though, that
enclave disappeared. Only in the past few years, as the
elven presence on Golarion has finally grown enough to
warrant it, have the elves returned to Darkmoon Vale."  That said, there's still a 1% pop, and it's a volcano.